# Bootstrap Navbar Responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

struggling to understand what I am doing wrong here.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Cyborg/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-responsive.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="navigation">

    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="brand" href="#">Project Name</a>
                    <div class="nav-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li><a href="/home.aspx">HOME</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/news.aspx">NEWS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/thingstodo.aspx">THINGS TO DO</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/business.aspx">BUSINESS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/sport.aspx">SPORT</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/villagelife.aspx">VILLAGE LIFE</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/talk.aspx">TALK</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container -->
        </div><!-- /.navbar-inner -->
    </div><!-- /.navbar -->
</div>
</body>
<script src="/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" />
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" />
</html>
```

The button appears under @media less than 940px but the button doesnt activate!

Getting quite frustrating now, have followed examples but just not getting anywhere

Any ideas please?

Comment: What do you mean by activate?

Comment: I've set up a fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/kbwLn/ Seems to be working fine, could you please elaborate on what the issue is? Are you 100% sure all your resources (js and css) are loading properly?

Answer (score 0):

The div containing the nav-collapse must contain `collapse` class. Also the bootstrap responsive css is required , so make sure its properly placed .

Do the following :

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
```

Make sure the two css files are in same directory its a good practice , you have them in following way

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Cyborg/bootstrap.css"> /*here in cyborg directory*/
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-responsive.css">/*put this one in Cyborg as well */
```

Place it in Cyborg directory like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Cyborg/bootstrap-responsive.css">
```

The jquery link seems to be the issue as well, use the following :

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
```

Comment: Thank you all, I have just discovered something rather silly. Chrome is working on the /> principle for <script>. <script></script> needed and now working.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I have just discovered something rather silly. Chrome is working on the /> principle for .  needed and now working.